# Running alembic command cause ImportError: cannot import name '_BindParamClause' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

This happens whenever I ran any `alembic` command. I am using sqlalchemy version 2.0.3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ado/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import op  # noqa
  File "/home/ado/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/op.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .operations.base import Operations
  File "/home/ado/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import Operations, BatchOperations
  File "/home/ado/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import util
  File "/home/ado/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .sqla_compat import (  # noqa
  File "/home/ado/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/sqla_compat.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import _BindParamClause
ImportError: cannot import name '_BindParamClause' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression' (/home/***/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved after uninstalling `alembic` and reinstalling it afresh

I ran:
`pip3 uninstall alembic`
`pip3 install alembic`